# Modifying Left Menu Navigation Functionality

Tags: javascript, css, menu

I being brushing my js and css skills by playing with a navigation menu. I am practicing with this code:

https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/30/google-nexus-website-menu/

A landing page show the burger icon menu only.
What I wish to show is the landing page with the burger icon and the left icons
Then on mouse over show the text description.

[image: Here is the original landing page screen shot:]

[image: The screen shot is what i wish to accomplish when opening the landing page:]

[image: Then when on mouse over show the text as the below shot]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Also let me know if my question is not clear, please

mp

Comment: So where's the code that you're brushing up your skills with?

Comment: Hi Serg, thanks for looking at it, the code is at this link: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/30/google-nexus-website-menu/

Comment: Sorry, this is not how SO works. First of all, that's a tutorial that you can follow yourself. Second, you're supposed to come here with code of your own and a specific problem, nobody is going to program websites or features for you.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, i just needed to modify my css and js file very simple issue. Thanks everyone for reading my post. Really cool small script from Mary :) I enjoyed it!!